# Unlock protected workbook without knowing password

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck with a problem, I'm creating a automation to automatically fill a report with spreadsheets downloaded from a website. however these sheets comes protected with a password, I've found a code to unlock the workbook without having to provide a password, however isn't working on excel 2016, anybody knows some other way?

Here's the code I have:

```
Sub UnProtect_Excel_WorkSheet()
    'Unlock Protect Excel Worksheet
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer, j1 As Integer, j2 As Integer, j3 As Integer
    Dim k1 As Integer, k2 As Integer, k3 As Integer, l1 As Integer, l2 As Integer, l3 As Integer
    Dim a As Double

    On Error Resume Next
    a = 0
    'Try all Possible Alternate Combination Password
    For i1 = 65 To 66: For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66
    For j1 = 65 To 66: For j2 = 65 To 66: For j3 = 65 To 66
    For k1 = 65 To 66: For k2 = 65 To 66: For k3 = 65 To 66
    For l1 = 65 To 66: For l2 = 65 To 66: For l3 = 32 To 126
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Unprotect Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & Chr(j1) & Chr(j2) & Chr(j3) & Chr(k1) & Chr(k2) & Chr(k3) & Chr(l1) & Chr(l2) & Chr(l3)
        a = a + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(a, 1) = Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & Chr(j1) & Chr(j2) & Chr(j3) & Chr(k1) & Chr(k2) & Chr(k3) & Chr(l1) & Chr(l2) & Chr(l3)

        'Check if the Protection is Removed
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
            MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & Chr(j1) & Chr(j2) & Chr(j3) & Chr(k1) & Chr(k2) & Chr(k3) & Chr(l1) & Chr(l2) & Chr(l3)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Exit Loop
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps silly - if you're downloading these files for a report, can you not ask the uploader the password? Or is this not a work-related thing where you could get that?  Also, does this throw any errors in 2016, or just not unlock the workbook?  If no errors are thrown, remove (or comment out) the `On Error Resume Next` to see what it is.

Comment: Starting in Excel 2013 and after, the bruteforce way (your code) no longer works. The only way that I know that still exists is by changing the excel file to a zip and deleting the password through the xml.

Comment: @rwilson, mind sharing how to do that? our team actually has a few files locked by a former employee who left without sharing the pw...

Comment: @acousticismX  I rather not do it here since this question is asking for an automated way of doing it and the way I'm planning on showing you is a manual step by step process.  Please create a new question and I will answer it later tonight.  Also, maybe someone has already provided a similar answer here on stackoverflow and can provide a link.

Comment: I wonder why `A` and `B` are considered only for the characters (except the last one). Also it would speed up things if the password is evaluated once and stored in a local variables instead of repeating `Chr() &Chr()&..` all over the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock any locked Excel Sheet when password is forgot without Software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520121/how-to-unlock-any-locked-excel-sheet-when-password-is-forgot-without-software)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. The solution I found is quite simple - just save the document as .xls and run the script.

This is a working solution if you have less than 65K rows.